# Is type casting structs in Go a no-op?

Tags: go, casting

Consider the following code in Go

```golang
type A struct {
  f int
}

type B struct {
  f int `somepkg:"somevalue"`
}


func f() {
  var b *B = (*B)(&A{1}) // <-- THIS

  fmt.Printf("%#v\n", b)
}
```

Will the marked line result in a memory copy (which I would like to avoid as A has many fields attached to it) or will it be just a reinterpretation, similar to casting an `int` to an `uint`?

**EDIT**: I was concerned, whether the whole struct would have to be copied, similarly to converting a byte slice to a string. A pointer copy is therefore a *no-op* for me

Comment: Any `foo = bar` causes a copy, because it is updating the value of `foo` to contain the value of `bar`. In this case, both are pointers so the values are addresses, but it's not a no-op, it's a copy.

Comment: Go doesn't support type casting at all. I don't know if that counts as a "no-op", but it's certainly not a thing. What you have in your code is a type conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crucial points to understand is that

First, unlike C, C++ and some other languages of their ilk, Go does not have type casting, it has [type conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

In most, but not all, cases, type conversion changes the type but not the internal representation of a value.

Second, as to whether a type conversion "is a no-op", depends on how you define the fact of being a no-op.

If you are concerned with a memory copy being made, there are two cases:

- Some type conversions are defined to drastically change the value's representation or to copy memory; for example:

  - Type-converting a value of type `string` to `[]rune` would interpret the value as a UTF-8-encoded byte stream, decode each encoded Unicode code point and produce a freshly-allocated slice of decoded Unicode runes.
  - Type-converting a value of type `string` to `[]byte`, and vice-versa, will clone the backing array underlying the value.
- Other type-conversions are no-op in this sense but in order for them to be useful you'd need to either assign a type-converted value to some variable or to pass it as an argument to a function call or send to a channel etc — in other words, you have to store the result or otherwise make use of it.
  All of such operations do copy the value, even though it does not "look" like this; consider:

  ```golang
  package main

  import (
      "fmt"
  )

  type A struct {
      X int
  }

  type B struct {
      X int
  }

  func (b B) Whatever() {
      fmt.Println(b.X)
  }

  func main() {
      a := A{X: 42}
      B(a).Whatever()

      b := B(a)
      b.Whatever()
  }
  ```

  Here, the first type conversion in `main` does not look like a memory copy, but the resulting value will serve as a receiver in the call to `B.Whatever` and will be physically copied there.
  The second type conversion stores the result in a variable (and then copies it again when a method is called).

  Reasonong about such things is easy in Go as there everything, always, is passed by value (and pointers are values, too).

---

It may worth adding that variables in Go does not store the type of the value they hold, so a type conversion cannot mutate the type of a variable "in place". Values do not have type information stored *in* them, either. This basically means that type conversions is what compiler is concerned with: it knows the types of all the participating values and variables and performs type checking.

Answer (score 5):

It is called a conversion. The expression `(&A{})` creates a pointer to an instance of type `A`, and `(*B)` converts that pointer to a `*B`. What's copied there is the pointer, not the struct. You can validate this using the following code:

```
 a:=A{}
 var b *B = (*B)(&a)
 b.f=2
 fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a)
```

Prints 2.